# How can I leave generic type params unrealized in an interface implementation?

Tags: generics, f#

lets say I have the following generic interface

```
type IStorageX<'a, 'b> =
    abstract Make: 'a -> 'b
    abstract From: 'c -> 'b
```

And the following 2 types

```
type SomeInput<'a> = {value : 'a}

type SomeThing = {value: string}
    with interface IStorageX<int, SomeThing> with
        member this.Make x = {value = sprintf "%A" x}    
        member this.From (x:SomeInput<'a>) = {value = sprintf "%A" x.value}
```

How can I make F# understand that `member From` should allow for any kind of input (as long as it is `SomeInput`)?

What I ned to try to some degree is

```
type IStorageX<'a, 'b, 'c> =
    abstract Make: 'a -> 'b
    abstract From: 'c -> 'b

type SomeThing = {value: string}
    with interface IStorageX<int, SomeThing, SomeInput<'a>> with
                                                     //^^--- unrealized generic param here
        member this.Make x = {value = sprintf "%A" x}    
        member this.From x = {value = sprintf "%A" x.value}
```

but that does also not compile as I may not have generic type params on interfaces that are not realized.

The only way I could do it is like this

```
type SomeThing = {value: string}
    with interface IStorageX<int, SomeThing, SomeInput<int>> with
        member this.Make x = {value = sprintf "%A" x}    
        member this.From (x:SomeInput<'a>) = {value = sprintf "%A" x.value}
```

that is to fully formulate all generic params. This of course doesn't work as I would have to realize them for every single type of SomeInput ...

Any idea on how to do that?

Thx

PS: I was able to define a solution using SRTP pretty fast. But I want a interface based solution as SRTP are somehow bad and everybody in F# land is like "no, no, no! nasty boy!"

Comment: CLR supports neither restricting interfaces at implementation (because that's nonsensical) nor higher-kinded plymorphism (just because). If you _really_ need this to work, there is nothing wrong with statically resolved constraints. But do you _really_ need this to work?

Comment: By "do I need that?" you mean the "interface-approach"? no, as I a have implemented it via SRTPs. Is your question: Do I need a generic approach? Oh yes ;-) I just wanted to be a nice boy and do it the traditional F# way <sigh>

Comment: nevertheless, what I dont understand: I have defined `abstract From: 'c -> 'b` when I implementing that member with any concrete type (and without putting that additional type param in the param list of the interface) the compiler gives me an error telling that the type I used is not `'c`. well that is correct but there is no type `'c`. So the question is why am I even allowed to define an interface that has a generic type parameter in one of its abstract members that is NOT part of the type parameters of the interface itself

Comment: maybe you could check http://eiriktsarpalis.github.io/typeshape/#/ ? but not sure it would solve the prb here...

Comment: Do you you always use SomeInput<'a> in From ? or sometime you also use SomeOtherInput<'a> ?

Comment: @thinkbeforecoding the important part of that interface is `From` and `Make` return the same type. And they have different input param types. That input type itself could be generic (in both cases) but no it would be completely different type apart from the generic param I need to provide. At least if we disregard the fact that any generic instantiation of a type is a different type for the CLR

Comment: Interface is a "promise" to the consumer, and a "demand" on the implementer. When you define an interface method as `'a -> 'b`, it means that "_every implementation must be able to accept any type `'a` that a consumer passes in_". Your implementation can't restrict the input to a narrower set of types than defined in the interface declaration, otherwise what would happen if some consumer calls the method with a "wrong" type of argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be very helpful for you to include more detail on exactly what you're really trying to accomplish, both from the implementation side and the consumer side - without that it's hard to infer what the best idiomatic solution would be.  Building off of your second example, it seems like maybe what you wish you could do is take

```
type IStorageX<'a, 'b, 'c> =
    abstract Make: 'a -> 'b
    abstract From: 'c -> 'b
```

and have your type `SomeThing` implement `IStorageX<int, SomeThing, SomeInput<'a>>` for any `'a`, but there's no way to do this - a type can't implement `forall 'a.I<'a>` in the .NET type system.  However, instead of implementing an interface, you could provide a method instead:

```
type SomeThing = 
    {value:string}
    member this.AsStorage() = { 
        new IStorageX<int,SomeThing,SomeInput<'a>> with 
            member this.Make x = {value = sprintf "%A" x}    
            member this.From (x:SomeInput<'a>) = {value = sprintf "%A" x.value}
    }
```